# How much Legendary Power is needed to double the damage of a full-attack?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items, mythic-adventures

In the description for the abilities of Legendary items we can read:

> **Foe-Biting**: When this item deals damage, its user can use mythic power to double the total amount of damage it deals. If the attack is a normal attack, the bearer can expend one use of legendary power to double the total amount of damage. If the attack is a confirmed critical hit, the bearer must instead expend two uses of legendary power to double the total damage. Damage from weapon special abilities (such as flaming) and precision-based damage are also doubled. This ability can be applied only to weapons. An item must be a minor or major artifact to have this ability.

Will a two-handed fighter with a Legendary Greatsword need to spend 5 Legendary Power to double the damage of all of his 5 attacks or only one Legendary power?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### One to Two uses each time you deal damage.

> When this item deals damage, its user can use mythic power to double the total amount of damage it deals. If the attack is a normal attack, the bearer can expend one use of legendary power to double the total amount of damage. Damage from weapon special abilities (such as flaming) and precision-based damage are also doubled.

This means that each time you deal damage with the weapon, you can spend one use of mythic power to activate foe-biting and double the damage dealt (including damage from weapon special abilities).

> If the attack is a confirmed critical hit, the bearer must instead expend two uses of legendary power to double the total damage.

If the attack is a critical hit, you would have to spend two uses instead.

Something to note here, is that you only spend mythic power when you're dealing damage. So you don't declare that you're using the ability until you've hit and are dealing damage to the foe.

So in this case, if the two-handed fighter made 5 attacks, they would be able to spend between 0-2 mythic power on each attack, depending on whether they missed, hit, or crit. If all 5 attacks were regular hits (no crits), they would need to spend 1 mythic power on each of the attacks they wish to double for a total of 5 mythic power spent. If all 5 attacks were crits, they would instead need to spend 2 uses of mythic power on each attack for a total of 10 mythic power.

Comment: Thanks to wheatleycrab and willuwontu to correct my mistakes: It looks like i came back to school: I love it.