# How much legendary power is needed to attack touch AC of a full attack?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items

In the description for the abilities of [Legendary items](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/alternative-rule-systems/mythic/mythic-magic-items/legendary-items/) we can read:

***Unstoppable Strike**: This weapon bypasses all armor. The wielder can expend one use of legendary power when attacking to make the attack against touch AC. If she instead expends two uses of legendary power, the weapon also bypasses any deflection bonus to AC the target has. An item must be a weapon and be a minor or major artifact to have this ability.*

Will a two-handed fighter's complete attack (for example 5 attacks) with a Legendary Greatsword spend 1 Legendary Power each attack against touch AC? So 5 attacks uses 5 uses of legendary powers?

Comment: I did not downvote, but I guess you are getting downvotes as this question is very similar to your other question.

Comment: Thank you for not downvote, I want to be sure about the sentences meanings, which are a bit different" 'cause you know sometimes words have two meanings".

Comment: and to stop the war against my GM.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### You need to spend power for each of your attacks

Similar to [your other question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/203146/how-much-legendary-power-is-needed-to-double-the-damage-of-a-full-attack), the power tells you

> The wielder can **expend one use** of legendary power when attacking **to make the attack** against touch AC.

You can spend one use of legendary power to make one attack.

If your whole attack routine involves 5 attacks, you could opt to spend anywhere between 0 and 10 legendary power, depending on which of the attacks you do want, or not want, to use touch AC or use touch AC and also bypass deflection bonuses.

So for example, if you wanted all 5 attacks to use touch AC, you would spend 5 legendary power. If you wanted all 5 attacks to use touch AC and also bypass deflection bonuses, you would spend 10 legendary power.